# rJava passing int to constructor

Tags: r, java-native-interface, rjava

I defined a java class with several constructors with different parameters. If I try to create a java object in R via `obj<-.jnew('testRJava/TestRJava', "Hello", "World")` or `obj<-.jnew('testRJava/TestRJava', "Hello world")` everthing working as expected. But if I try to pass an Integer like `obj<-.jnew('testRJava.TestRJava', "Hello", 123)` the following error is thrown:

> Error in .jnew("testRJava/TestRJava", "Hello", 123) :
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>

On Java side I definitly defined the constructor `public TestRJava(String param1, int param2) {...` and the rjava doc says:

> Any parameters that will be passed to the corresponding constructor.
> The parameter types are determined automatically and/or taken from the
> jobjRef object. For details see .jcall. Note that all named parameters
> are discarded.

But I can't find how to pass an integer. Do I have to use `.jcast` or anything else?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, it's been a long time, thx :))

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Can you write that as an answer for future readers so OP can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

123 is a double. 123L is a (long) integer.